# How can I render the line in the game mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to render the line in the game mode of the 3d project as shown in the screenshot below:

[Please, see the screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m0y6.png)

My code is below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pointer : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject currentHitObject;
    private float currentHitDistance;
    private Vector3 origin;
    private Vector3 direction;
    public float maxDistance;
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        origin = transform.position;
        direction = transform.forward;
       
      
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider)
            {
                //currentHitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                currentHitDistance = hit.distance;
                Debug.Log("Done");
            }
            else
            {
                currentHitDistance = maxDistance;
                currentHitObject = null;
            }
        }


    }


    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(origin, origin + direction * currentHitDistance);
        Gizmos.DrawIcon(origin + direction * currentHitDistance, "CrossIcon");
     }
}
```

I tried to make some settings adjustments on the unity but the problem is not solved. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Do you want to render the gizmo for debugging reasons? You should be able to toggle the "Gizmos" button on the [game view tab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html). If you want to render them in game for the player to view, you have to draw them with a different logic, e.g. the [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful component that Unity provides for drawing lines in Game View is `LineRenderer`. In the first step, put one on your object and cache its value in the variable.

```cs
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private void Start()
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
}
```

The next problem you have in your code is that `if (hit.collider)` in this code will never reach `else`, that raycast only returns true when it collides, therefore `hit.Collider` must always exist there. I modified your code as below which hopefully solves the problem.

```cs
RaycastHit hit;
origin = transform.position;
direction = transform.forward;

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
{
    currentHitDistance = hit.distance;

    lineRenderer.enabled = true;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, origin);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
}
else
{
    lineRenderer.enabled = false;
    currentHitDistance = maxDistance;
    currentHitObject = null;
}
```

---

### Adding Cross

To add a cross to the end of Ray, you need to have a cross-like game object. I simply created one where it is important that the forward axis is perpendicular to the lines.

[image: Cross.H]

[image: Cross.GV]

Next step to avoid the collision of the ray with the cross, set its layer to `IgnoreRaycast` and it is better to remove the colliders.

[image: Ignore Raycast]

[image]

After specifying the object on the inspector, by adding the code snippet below, make it tangent to normal hit and the problem will be solved.

```cs
[SerializeField] private GameObject cross;

...

if (Physics.Raycast...)
{
    ...
    cross.SetActive(true); // unhide cross
    cross.transform.position = hit.point;
    cross.transform.forward = hit.normal;
    ...
}
else
{
    cross.SetActive(false); // hide cross
}
```

Comment: That is fine, but how can I put the cross at the end of the line?

Comment: @saad read the answer updates.

Comment: everything now is ok except the position of the cross it is in the middle of the line, I created an empty object and added two cubes to it. I do not know where the mistake is.

Comment: @saad Place the cross boxes exactly in the center of the parent and set the local position to zero.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see the line in the editor, there is a **"Gizmos"** button on the top right corner of the Game window, toggle it on.

If you want to draw a line in a released program, check the example code of the [`GL.Vertex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.Vertex.html) method.

```
public Material mat;

void OnPostRender()
{
    GL.PushMatrix();
    mat.SetPass(0);
    GL.LoadOrtho();
    GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
    GL.Vertex(origin);
    GL.Vertex(origin + direction * currentHitDistance);
    GL.End();
    GL.PopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: I got the following error: "GL.End requires material.SetPass before!"  I added like mat.SetPass(0) or 1 also is not working.

Comment: Have a look at the link, you need to choose a material first.

Comment: And note that the script should be associate with a camera: [Monobehaviour.OnPostRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html)